# rabbitmq consumer doesn't accept the post request after it started to run on server

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have a spring boot application that acts as both producer and consumer with some changes. When I run it as producer, the application is running fine and Im able to post message from postman(I can see the message arriving in the rabbitmq exchange as well, though I cannot see any created there). But, when I run the application as consumer, the application runs without errors. But, when I try to post

```
2022-06-15 12:45:21.077 ERROR 11464 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Could not read JSON: Unrecognized token 'TemplateRequest': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"TemplateRequest(templateField=abc)"; line: 1, column: 16]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'TemplateRequest': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"TemplateRequest(templateField=abc)"; line: 1, column: 16], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=TemplateRequest(templateField=abc), headers={id=1d60161d-0de4-3b32-7c5f-30a5bf8e6ce0, message=abc, type=io.overledger.springboottemplateservice.dto.TemplateRequest, contentType=application/json, processTime=1655293488245, timestamp=1655293520838}]] with root cause

com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'TemplateRequest': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')
 at [Source: (String)"TemplateRequest(templateField=abc)"; line: 1, column: 16]
```

When I tried to debug the sequence of execution I can see the proper execution until it reaches publishegateway interface and then it ends up with the above exception. As this interface is working with "@Gateway(requestChannel = TemplateOutputChannel.CHANNEL_NAME)", there is no implementation class to debug more.

Here is the code:

Publisher:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBinding(TemplateOutputChannel.class)
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class TemplateConfig {

}
```

Consumer:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBinding(TemplateOutputChannel.class)
@IntegrationComponentScan
@FieldDefaults(level = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class TemplateChannelHandler {

    TemplateService templateService;
    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @StreamListener(TemplateOutputChannel.CHANNEL_NAME)
    public void stateChannelHandler(@Payload String payload, @Header("message") String message, @Header("processTime") Long processTime, @Header("type") String type) throws JsonProcessingException {
        TemplateRequest templateRequest = null;
        if (type.equals(TemplateRequest.class.getName())) {
            templateRequest = this.objectMapper.readValue(payload, TemplateRequest.class);
        }
        if (templateRequest != null) {
            log.info(String.format("Processing templateRequest: %s, templateField: %s, dispatch timestamp: %d, message type: %s.", templateRequest.getTemplateField(), message, processTime, type));
            this.templateService.saveToDatabase(templateRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

Output/InputChannel:

```
public interface TemplateOutputChannel {

    String CHANNEL_NAME = "template-channel";

    // To use as an input channel together with the TemplateChannelHandler, use the @Input annotation instead of @Output.
    @Input(TemplateOutputChannel.CHANNEL_NAME)
    MessageChannel templateChannel();
}
```

Publish gateway:

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface TemplatePublishGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = TemplateOutputChannel.CHANNEL_NAME)
    void templatePublishRequest(@Payload TemplateRequest templateRequest, @Header("message") String message, @Header("processTime") Long processTime, @Header("type") String type);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the serialization of the json payload of the message you're trying to send. It needs to verify against your TemplateRequest.

Comment: TemplateRequest has only one attribute called templateField. So I'm inputting the json data as:

{
   "templateField": "somemessage"
}